# specify the broacast interface with tidudpclient in delphi

Tags: delphi, interface, broadcast

I am creating an application through delphi which broadcasts a message through UDP to a electronic board. sending and receiving works great if only the lan interface is up, but, if I turn on the wlan interface (two interfaces up) the messages are not received and there is no response.
I am taking the guess that the tipudpclient sends the message through the wrong interface (wlan). is there a way to change the broadcasting inteface? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `BoundIP` property to specify the local IP of the desired interface that `TIdUDPClient` should bind to.

Comment: It seems that that property is only availible on the newer versions of indy, I am using delphi6 with the native version of indy, I didn't find that property, is there another solution?

Comment: The `TIdUDPClient.BoundIP` property was introduced in Indy 10. Delphi 6 shipped with Indy 8. In Indy 8 and 9, you would have to manually set the `TIdUDPClient.Binding.IP` property and then call the `TIdUDPClient.Binding.Bind()` method directly. The best place to do that would be to derive a new class from `TIdUDPClient` and override the virtual `GetBinding()` method.